# XSL 2.0: Calling templates according to predefined attributes

Tags: templates, xslt, attributes, xslt-2.0

I try to transform in XSLT 2.0

```
<data>
  <attributes>
    <attribute code="Name" datatyp="String" class="A"></attribute>
    <attribute code="Age" datatyp="Integer" class="A"></attribute>
    <attribute code="sex" datatyp="String" class="A"></attribute>
    <attribute code="height" datatyp="Integer" class="B"></attribute>
  </attributes>
  <personal>
    <name>Klaus</name>
    <Age>16</Age>
    <sex>male</sex>
    <height>180</height>
  </personal>
  <personal>
    <height>165</height>
  </personal>
</data>
```

into something like that for Person 1

```
<personal>
  <class>
    <classtype>A</classtype>
    <name>Klaus</name>
    <Age>16</Age>
    <sex>male</sex>
  </class>
  <class>
    <classtype>B</classtype>
    <height>180</height>
  </class> 
</personal>
<personal>
  <class>
    <classtype>B</classtype>
    <height>165</height>
  </class> 
</personal>
```

Where the dependencies which attribute appears in which class are defined in the beginning of the Input XML. I need to call the templates for class A and B only once per Person, that's why my attempts like the following are not working.

```
<xsl:for-each select="...personal/*">   
  <xsl:variable name="code"><xsl:value-of select="name()"></xsl:value-of> </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:if test="//attribute[@code=$code]/@class='A'">
    <!-- call template A -->
```

I need some help to solve the problem of calling the right templates according to the given parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="attr-by-code" match="attribute" use="@code" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="personal">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="key('attr-by-code', name())/@class">
            <class> 
                <classtype>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                </classtype>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </class>
        </xsl:for-each-group>   
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attributes"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simpler, more than twice shorter, preserving order and really correct**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:key name="kAttrByCode" match="attribute" use="@code"/>

  <xsl:template match="personal">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*[key('kAttrByCode', name())]" 
                          group-adjacent="key('kAttrByCode', name())/@class">
        <class>
          <classtype><xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key()"/></classtype>
          <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
        </class>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (note that `code="Name"` is corrected to `code="name"` -- otherwise a case conversion function must be used to achieve case insensibility):

```
<data>
    <attributes>
        <attribute code="name" datatyp="String" class="A"></attribute>
        <attribute code="Age" datatyp="Integer" class="A"></attribute>
        <attribute code="sex" datatyp="String" class="A"></attribute>
        <attribute code="height" datatyp="Integer" class="B"></attribute>
    </attributes>
    <personal>
        <name>Klaus</name>
        <Age>16</Age>
        <sex>male</sex>
        <height>180</height>
    </personal>
    <personal>
        <height>165</height>
    </personal>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<personal>
   <class>
      <classtype>A</classtype>
      <name>Klaus</name>
      <Age>16</Age>
      <sex>male</sex>
   </class>
   <class>
      <classtype>B</classtype>
      <height>180</height>
   </class>
</personal>
<personal>
   <class>
      <classtype>B</classtype>
      <height>165</height>
   </class>
</personal>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using the `<xsl:for-each-group>` instruction with the attribute `group-adjacent`
2. Using the standard XSLT functions `current-group()` and `current-grouping-key()`

Comment: The result produced here is not well-formed XML (does not have a single root element). -- And I don't see anything in the question to suggest that  properties of the same class are adjacent in the source XML. If the order happens to be name, age, height, sex, this will create two A groups.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, There is no requirement for the result of an XSLT transformation to be a well-formed XML document. Setting (or defaulting)the `method` attribute of `<xsl:output>` to "xml" specifies that the XSLT processor should produce a *well-formed XML fragment* -- not a well-formed XML document: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-XML-Output-Method  . And the OP's required output is exactly this -- not a complete XML document. As for whether one or several groups should be created, this isn't specified by the OP -- my personal choice and understanding is to preserve order maximally.